# Проблема с ActionScript 3 Adobe Flash Pro

Tags: flash, actionscript

Недавно начал работать с adobe flash pro, в чем суть проблеммы: дело в том, что я сделал небольшой банер с блоками товаров, каждый блок имеет свою кнопку с присвоенной ссылкой, и блоки товаров менялись при переходе на следующий кадр (что-то типа слайдера), соответственно, также менялись ссылки.

Как бы казалось, на первом кадре все хорошо работает, но если сделать ссылки для второго кадра, то компилятор выбивает мне следующую ошибку:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at NonameFlash_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, целый час борюсь с проблемой, но толку 0.

Вот код:

```
// Первый кадр

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_1);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2);

// Второй кадр

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_4);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://site"), "_blank");
}
btnlink5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_5);
```

Явно коряво сделал. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самая ценная вещь, которую я понял при работе с ActionScript и Adobe Flash, - никогда не используйте для навигации главную временную шкалу, если не знаете на 100%, как она работает с переменными.

Я не вижу в Вашем коде проблему, но, я так понимаю, это и не весь код, который используется (как минимум, где код, отвечающий за переход между кадрами? Или как они меняются?). При переходе с одного ключевого кадра на другой все объявленные в одном кадре переменные перестают быть видимыми в другом, из-за чего, скорее всего, и возникает null ссылка.

Хотите не иметь много проблем, используйте контейнер MovieClip, уже в нем осуществляйте навигацию по ключевым кадрам и начинайте приложение с класса документа, где и храните необходимую информацию.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пожалуй, следует заглянуть в справочник adobe)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, действительно все работает)